# How to read filenames containing a number and only use those with less than or equal to a specified value, also how to make my 'cache' more efficient?

Tags: php

So I've got a couple of questions that I'm hoping someone will be able to help me with.

Firstly, I'm trying to create a page which parses information and organizes it by the hour into a table. At the moment my script parses the information with Simple HTML Dom and creates a text file for each hour called "hour_%time%.txt" (e.g. hour_02.txt, hour_14.txt, hour_22.txt). Each file will contain the parsed information as a table row.

How would I go about only using the files with times earlier than the current hour, so if the current hour was 9am, only files ending with equal to or less than 09 would be used? I was trying to use either explode or preg_match but I couldn't get it to work.

My code at the moment looks like so:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$currentHour = date('H');

$cache_file = 'cache/hour_'.$currentHour.'.txt';
$data = '<tr><td>'.date('H:00').'</td><td>'.$firmato_count.'</td><td>'.$inviato_count.'</td><td>'.$positive_count.'</td><td>'.$negative_count.'</td></tr>';
file_put_contents($cache_file, $data);

echo '<table class="table"><tbody>';
echo '<tr><th>Time</th><th>Firmato</th><th>Inviato</th><th>Positive</th><th>Negative</th></tr>';
$files = glob("cache/hour_*.txt");
foreach($files as $txt){
    $hourlyfile = file_get_contents($txt);
    echo $hourlyfile;
}
echo '</table></tbody>';
```

And secondly, I'm fully aware this isn't the best way to do this but I couldn't figure out a better way myself. Can anyone suggest a more efficient way to store the parsed data and access it? Is it possible to use a single file? I did consider appending the same file however as my page will update frequently it ended up adding multiple lines of data for the same hour. Each file contains a string like so:

```
<tr><td>10:00</td><td>21</td><td>58</td><td>4</td><td>43</td></tr>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your String of the hour to a number
[PHP]

```
$currentHour = intval($currentHour);
```

next compare

```
if($currentHour <= 9){ // < for less and <= for less and equal
    doStuff
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you. I went with your suggestion and used if/elsif to create three different search strings based on the current hour.

Answer (score 1):

This only will display the file of the exact hour. Tell me if doesn't work for edit it.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$currentHour = intval(date('H'));

$cache_file = 'cache/hour_'.$currentHour.'.txt';
$data = '<tr><td>'.date('H:00').'</td><td>'.$firmato_count.'</td><td>'.$inviato_count.'</td><td>'.$positive_count.'</td><td>'.$negative_count.'</td></tr>';
file_put_contents($cache_file, $data);

echo '<table class="table"><tbody>';
echo '<tr><th>Time</th><th>Firmato</th><th>Inviato</th><th>Positive</th><th>Negative</th></tr>';
$files = glob("cache/hour_*.txt");
if($currentHour == $currentHour){
    foreach($files as $txt){
        $hourlyfile = file_get_contents($txt);
        echo $hourlyfile;
    }
}
echo '</table></tbody>';
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. Wasn't quite what I was looking for. I needed to show everything from previous hours up until the current. I managed to do it by using COOLGAMETUBE's suggestion and created a variable called $globSearch and used if/elseif to create three different strings to search for based on the current hour. Appreciate you taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a variable called $globSearch and used if/elseif to create a search string based on the current hour. My code now looks like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$currentDate = date('d/m/Y');
$currentHour = intval(date('H'));
$cache_file = 'cache/hour_'.$currentHour.'.txt';
$data = '<tr><td>'.date('H:00').'</td><td>'.$firmato_count.'</td><td>'.$inviato_count.'</td><td>'.$positive_count.'</td><td>'.$negative_count.'</td></tr>';
file_put_contents($cache_file, $data);

echo '<table class="table"><tbody>';
echo '<tr><th>Time</th><th>Firmato</th><th>Inviato</th><th>Positive</th><th>Negative</th></tr>';
if ($currentHour <= 9) {
    $globSearch = "{cache/hour_[0][0-".$currentHour."].txt}";
} elseif ($currentHour >= 10 && $currentHour <= 19) {
    $splitInt = str_split($currentHour);
    $globSearch = "{cache/hour_[0][0-9].txt,cache/hour_[1][0-".$splitInt[1]."].txt}";
} elseif ($currentHour >= 20 && $currentHout <= 23) {
    $splitInt = str_split($currentHour);
    $globSearch = "{cache/hour_[0][0-9].txt,cache/hour_[1][0-9][2-".$splitInt[1]."].txt}";
}
//$files = glob("{cache/hour_[0][0-9].txt,cache/hour_[1][0-3].txt}", GLOB_BRACE);
$files = glob($globSearch, GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($files as $txt) {
        $hourlyfile = file_get_contents($txt);
        echo $hourlyfile;
}

echo '</table></tbody>';
```

Thanks for replying Ruben and COOLGAMETUBE, much appreciated.

Comment: No problem bro, feel cree to ask anytime and we are here to help!